# How to do the "I Spy" mission?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

I have been building imperial buildings, staying on the game for 1h+, and I can't find nothing. I am absolutely clueless. The description ("Curse these Rebel Spies! Bring me one of them!") is very vague, and I just have no idea. I'd rather not spend any tower bux if possible.

Comment: What does the description say exactly?

Comment: @Kecoey It says "Curse these Rebel Spies! Bring me one of them!"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To do the "I Spy" mission, you have to wait until you get a "catch the rebel spy" mission. Not even taking Leia down to Interrogation will meet the requirements. So just keep playing until a rebel spy mission pops up. It will happen eventually.

The "catch the rebel spy" mission will show up with the blue rebel logo button. When pressed, will ask you to find a specific bitizen (non-resident) in the Death Star. Finding this specific character and pressing the level you find it on will complete the "I Spy" mission.

Comment: By "mission" StarPilot means there will be a blue button notification that (when pressed) will ask you to find a specific bitizen (non-resident) in the death star. Very similar to the blue quests where you find one of your resident bitizens in exchange for a buck.

Comment: The icon in question is the Rebel logo, instead of a person, which are the find a bitizen missions.

Comment: Good points. Answer updated.